# Tornado Request with WebSocket Callback

Tags: python-3.x, websocket, tornado, python-asyncio

I'm trying to start a long blocking function after receiving an HTTP request. The request must be responded inmediately (200 OK or 500 Internal Error), but the process should run in the background and send a notification to a WebSocket after finished.

Also, the application should receive other requests for processing and these must also be responded inmediately, without blocking the previous ones.

I'm using add_callback, but I'm not sure if it's the correct way to use tornado, since it's blocking the incoming HTTP requests. I've tried using different threads, but I got exceptions when trying to call the  send_message method inside the WebSocket handler.

```
import time
from tornado import gen
from tornado.ioloop import IOLoop
from tornado.web import Application, RequestHandler, asynchronous
from tornado.websocket import WebSocketHandler


def long_process(id):
    time.sleep(5)


class RequestWeb(RequestHandler):
    @gen.coroutine
    def process(self, id):
        # Trying to call long_process, just like
        # yield gen.Task(IOLoop.current().add_timeout, time.time() + 10)
        # The response must be sent inmediately, but the process should run in the background
        IOLoop.current().add_callback(callback=lambda: long_process(id))

    @asynchronous
    @gen.coroutine
    def get(self, id):
        IOLoop.current().add_future(self.process(id), self.process_complete)
        self.write("OK")

    def process_complete(self, future):
        SocketHandler.send_message('Processing complete')


class SocketHandler(WebSocketHandler):
    connections = set()

    def open(self):
        SocketHandler.connections.add(self)

    @classmethod
    def send_message(cls, message):
        for ws in cls.connections:
            ws.write_message(message)


def make_app():
    return Application([
        (r'/api/(?P<id>[a-zA-Z0-9]+)$', RequestWeb),
        (r'/ws', SocketHandler)
    ])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = make_app()
    app.listen(8000)
    IOLoop.current().start()
```

Comment: Your approach is right, but you definitely have to move blocking long processing to a different thread or process. For threading see tornado's [run_on_executor](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/concurrent.html#tornado.concurrent.run_on_executor). For multiprocessing see [ProcessPoolExecutor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#processpoolexecutor).